# Add prefix / suffix to field by using template_preprocess_field

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I remember in Drupal 7, this was possible. I need to add some HTML before a field and I don't want to edit it in the Twig file. Is it somehow possible to add prefixes / suffixes by using the `template_preprocess_field` function?

I already tried something like that, but with no success:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
    $element = $variables['element'];
    if ($element['#field_name'] === 'field_genre') {
        $element[0]['#prefix'] = '<div class="project-info">';
    }
    if ($element['#field_name'] === 'field_duration') {
        $element[0]['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep that's still the same. You're just discarding the changes, you want `$element = &$variables['element'];`

Comment: Darn, that was stupid! Thanks! However, even after changing this, it won't work. Do I need to use the Delta Array? Or is prefix and suffix generally for a field rather than a single value inside it?

Comment: Yeah you might need to dig further down in the array - look for the child with `'#type' => 'textfield'` or `'#type' => 'select'` or whatever, that's the element that needs the prefix/suffix

Comment: Yes, you should be able to add a prefix/suffix to any render element, but not in `$variables['element']`, because in preprocess the fields are already copied to `$variables['items']`, see [template_preprocess_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8.5.x).

Comment: Thanks! I'm now able to create prefixes and suffixed. However, the prefix is rendered inside the `div.field__item` - I'd like to render it outside the `div.field` which is 2 levels above. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

to prefix a paragraph field, this needs to be put into mytheme.theme .

```
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraph(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['elements']['#paragraph']) && ($vars['elements']['#paragraph']->getType() == 'hp_dean')){
    //kint($vars);
    $vars['content']['field_hp_dean_title']['#prefix'] = '<div class="cont-wrap">';
    $vars['content']['field_hp_dean_more']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  }
}
```

you can adjust this to your specific hook, like hook_preprocess_node and similar .